# Reading/loading jks cert file in Java returns empty aliases

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I am trying to load and read values of cert file using KeyStore in Java. Here is snippet of my code to load jks file. 
It doesn't throw any exception but keyStore.aliases will not return anything and is empty.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());  
Class clazz = Matcher.class;
InputStream inputStream = clazz.getResourceAsStream("/mycert.jks");  
keyStore.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());   
Enumeration<String> keyStoreAliases = keyStore.aliases();
```

Meanwhile when I tried to list all alias of same .jks file using keytool like below,
 $ keytool -v -list -keystore mycert.jks
It list all info (alias and values) of the cert in console.

Can anyone help me to understand what am I missing here ?

Comment: Your keystore must be empty

Answer (score 1):

`KeyStore.load()` will most likely not throw any exception if supplied `InputStream` is null. This behaviour depends on the implementation however the usual `sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore` implementation doesn't throw.

It could be that there is no `/mycert.jks` file on your system.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mycert.jks");  
if (in == null) { 
  throw new NullPointerException("No JKS input stream");
}
```

Comment: correct the inputstream was null and KeyStore.load() will not throw any exception for null inputstream ! I correct the path and is working now.